# Constructing objects in __init__

Tags: python, constructor

I've seen code that looks something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, someargs):
        myObj = OtherClass()
        myDict = {}
        ...code to setup myObj, myDict...
        self.myObj = myObj
        self.myDict = myDict
```

My first thought when I saw this was: Why not just use self.myObj and self.myDict in the beginning?  It seems inefficient to construct local objects, then assign them to the members. The code to construct the objects do possibly throw exceptions, maybe they did this so it wouldn't leave a half-constructed object? Do you do this, or just construct the members directly?

Comment: I think you supplied the best reason. If I have a function that performs side effects, even if the side effects don't reach beyond self, I'll delay those effects until the function has successfully completed. It's a good habit in any function where there's the possibility of an exception halting execution midway through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's faster *and* more readable to construct the object and then attach it to `self`.

```
class Test1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        d = {}
        d['a'] = 1
        d['b'] = 2
        d['c'] = 3
        self.d = d

class Test2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}
        self.d['a'] = 1
        self.d['b'] = 2
        self.d['c'] = 3

import dis
print "Test1.__init__"
dis.dis(Test1.__init__)

print "Test2.__init__"
dis.dis(Test2.__init__)
```

disassemles to:

```
Test1.__init__
  4           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 STORE_FAST               1 (d)

  5           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a')
             15 STORE_SUBSCR        

  6          16 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             19 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 ('b')
             25 STORE_SUBSCR        

  7          26 LOAD_CONST               5 (3)
             29 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
             32 LOAD_CONST               6 ('c')
             35 STORE_SUBSCR        

  8          36 LOAD_FAST                1 (d)
             39 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             42 STORE_ATTR               0 (d)
             45 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             48 RETURN_VALUE        
Test2.__init__
 12           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              6 STORE_ATTR               0 (d)

 13           9 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                0 (d)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('a')
             21 STORE_SUBSCR        

 14          22 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             25 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             28 LOAD_ATTR                0 (d)
             31 LOAD_CONST               4 ('b')
             34 STORE_SUBSCR        

 15          35 LOAD_CONST               5 (3)
             38 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             41 LOAD_ATTR                0 (d)
             44 LOAD_CONST               6 ('c')
             47 STORE_SUBSCR        
             48 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             51 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that `STORE_ATTR` only gets called once doing it the first way at the end. Doing it the other way, `STORE_ATTR` still gets called right at the beginning but now `LOAD_ATTR` gets called for every access to the dictionary. The more assignments there are, the higher the cost.  Every other instruction is the same. It's still a ridiculously small cost.

This trick can be exploited to make loops with many iterations run faster. It's not uncommon to see things like

```
foo = self.foo
factorial = math.factorial
for x in really_big_iterator:
    foo(factorial(x))
```

another trick is to pass global functions as default arguments to a function that has a loop like that or gets called a whole bunch to save some attribute lookups: it's in the local scope which is the first one looked in.

```
def fast(iterators, sum=sum):
    for i in iterator:
        yield sum(i)
```

now sum is right in the local scope.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about the performance implication of copying an object reference, you are probably using the wrong language :)

Do what's more readable to you. In this case, it depends on how long is the init method.

Comment: I'm only worried in the sense of avoiding premature pessimization :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but keep in mind that assigning `self.myObj = myObj` will simply assign a reference so it isn't likely to slow things down much. My guess is that idiom is being used to save the programmer from typing the word `self` a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no significant difference either way. One reason to create a local variable is if you are going to use the variable in __init__ a lot, you don't have to repeat the `self.` so much. e.g.

```
def __init__(self, someargs):
    self.myObj = OtherClass()
    self.myDict = {}
    self.myDict[1] = self.myObj
    self.myDict[2] = self.myObj
    self.myDict[3] = self.myObj
    self.myDict[4] = self.myObj
    self.myObj = myObj
    self.myDict = myDict
```

v.s.

```
def __init__(self, someargs):
    obj = OtherClass()
    d = {}
    d[1] = obj
    d[2] = obj
    d[3] = obj
    d[4] = obj
    self.myObj = obj
    self.myDict = d
```

I won't worry performance so much unless you have a good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a reference doesn't take too much time, but typing 'self' each time does take you time.